# Cannot use JS (Harmony) WeakMap in GWT : "delete" method name treated as keyword?

Tags: javascript, gwt

I am trying to build a GWT wrapper over JavaScript WeakMap. The WeakMap API defines a method called "delete" (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) for example). But using this method causes a compilation error in GWT:

```
...
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 77: missing name after . operator
[INFO] >             this.map.delete(key);
...
```

It *looks like (to me)* as if the GWT compiler (gwt-maven-plugin v2.6.0) interprets all occurrence of the word "delete" as a "keyword".

How could I work-around that issue?

```
...
private native void init()
/*-{
    this.map = new window.WeakMap();
}-*/;

/** Constructor */
public MyWeakKeyMap() {
    init();
}
...
public native VALUE remove(final Object key)
/*-{
    var result = this.map.get(key);
    this.map.delete(key);
    return result;
}-*/;
...
```

Comment: What is `VALUE` here?

Comment: @Braj VALUE and KEY are generic parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way around it, which compiles in GWT:

```
private native void init()
/*-{
    this.map = new $wnd.WeakMap();
    this.map.rmv = this.map['delete'];
}-*/;
public native VALUE remove(final Object key)
/*-{
    var result = this.map.get(key);
    this.map.rmv(key);
    return result;
}-*/;
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `$wnd` inside GWT JSNI instead of `window`

```
private native void init()
/*-{
   this.map = new $wnd.WeakMap();
}-*/;
```

---

or try in this way

```
// create a instance variable in your MyWeakKeyMap class for WeakMap 
// instead of creating it in JavaScript itself
protected JavaScriptObject nativeWeakMap;

private native void init()
/*-{
   var theInstance = this;
   theInstance.@com.x.x.z.MyWeakKeyMap::nativeWeakMap = new $wnd.WeakMap();
}-*/;

public native VALUE remove(final Object key)
/*-{
    var theInstance = this;
    var result = theInstance.@com.x.x.z.MyWeakKeyMap::nativeWeakMap.get(key);
    theInstance.@com.x.x.z.MyWeakKeyMap::nativeWeakMap.delete(key);
    return result;
}-*/;
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have included more code. "this.map" is defined in JSNI too, not Java, so that I don't have to use that ridiculously complicated notation. Will update question test.

Comment: It should be `$wnd` inside GWT JSNI instead of `window`. Isn't it?

Comment: Are you able to access map in remove method?

Comment: It's not the access to the field. It really is only the "delete" method that is not available *in the GWT compiler*. As an example, this works, and compiles, as expected: "var map = new $wnd.WeakMap(); map.set(key, 'xxx'); return map.get(key);" But "map.delete(key);" does not even compile.

Comment: but at least you were using `window` instead of `$wnd` that you have corrected.

Comment: just try with my second approach

Comment: OK. I did. No dice. Still won't let me call delete() with same error message. But I have a work-around now, so I'll post it as answer.